# Jaccard Index Python

Tags: python, set, distance, normalization, similarity

I want to use Jaccard Index to find the similarity between two sets.
I found a Jaccard Index implementation here: `http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html` but the input of the funciton of the library have to be a `List`, while in my case I prefer `Set`.

I wrote this code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score



def jaccard_index(first_set, second_set):
    """ Computes jaccard index of two sets
        Arguments:
          first_set(set):
          second_set(set):
        Returns:
          index(float): Jaccard index between two sets; it is
            between 0.0 and 1.0
    """
    # If both sets are empty, jaccard index is defined to be 1
    index = 1.0
    if first_set or second_set:
        index = (float(len(first_set.intersection(second_set)))
             / len(first_set.union(second_set)))

    return index

y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 3, 5]
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7]
a={0,2,1,3,5}
b={0,1,2,3,7}
print jaccard_similarity_score(y_true, y_pred)
print jaccard_similarity_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=False)
print(jaccard_index(a,b))
```

These are the outputs of the 3 print:

```
0.4
2
0.666666666667
```

Why are they different from my implementation (0.666666666667)?
Why is the second result 2? Shouldn't the Jaccard Index be between 0 and 1?
Which one is the best implementation and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
If normalize == True, return the average Jaccard similarity coefficient,
else it returns the sum of the Jaccard similarity coefficient over the sample set.
```

By the way, you can see the code of sklearn implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L374)

__

I see now the main problem - it is due to the nature of sets. You have the line a={0,2,1,3,5}. After this a becames equal to {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, because using set causes automatical sorting of the data. a and b are sorted independently from each other, and as a result similarity is calculated not between original lists, but different lists. So you can't use set, because original position of elements is important.

Comment: I see now the main problem - it is due to the nature of sets. You have the line a={0,2,1,3,5}. After this a becames equal to {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, because using set causes automatical sorting of the data. a and b are sorted independently from each other, and as a result similarity is calculated not between original lists, but different lists. So you can't use set, because original position of elements is important.